# JavaScript: Escape (encode?) special characters in filenames

Tags: character-encoding, javascript

I have a JavaScript that runs an external program (mediainfo) on local files.  However, some of my files have characters that mess up my code.

The code:

```
 objMedInfo = JSON.parse(proc.execSync('mediainfo "' + currentfilename + '" --output=JSON').toString());
```

The problem is that if currentfilename contains a quotation mark or some other extended characters, the command fails.

Is there a way to escape or encode currentfilename to prevent this?  It's not feasible to rename all the potential files.

Comment: I've also tried in the form proc.exec('mediainfo', [currentfile, '--output=JSON']) but fails even worse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `execFileSync` instead of `execSync`. This allows you to supply the arguments in an array, rather than putting everything in a string that has to be parsed by the shell.

```
objMedInfo = JSON.parse(proc.execFileSync('mediainfo', [currentfilename, '--output=JSON']).toString());
```